Error ‘3075’ en tiempo de ejecución en Access
Cordial saludo agradezco por favor la colaboración que me puedan brindar con el siguiente inconveniente, estoy realizando la siguiente consulta en Access con VBA:
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Max(Observaciones)] as Saldo_anterior " & _
              "FROM Concepto WHERE Concepto.IdCtaCobro IN (SELECT TOP 1 [RecibodeIngresos.IdCtaCobro] " & _
              "FROM RecibodeIngresos WHERE Númdedocidentif= '" & [Forms]![frm_ProveedoresRecibodeingresosconcepto]![Númdedocidentif] & "'")

If Not rs.EOF Then
   MsgBox "Hola el registro es: " & rs.Fields(0)
End If

Al ejecutar el código me muestra  el siguiente error:
Se ha producido el error ‘3075’ en tiempo de ejecución:
Falta ), ] o un elemento en la expresión de consulta ‘Concepto.IdCtaCobro IN (SELECT TOP 1 RecibodeIngresos.IdCtaCobro FROM RecibodeIngresos WHERE Númdedocidentif=’0402’’.
Para arreglar el inconveniente he modificado la consulta de la siguiente manera removiendo los paréntesis cuadrados [], quedando la consulta así:
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Max(Observaciones) as Saldo_anterior " & _
              "FROM Concepto WHERE Concepto.IdCtaCobro IN (SELECT TOP 1 RecibodeIngresos.IdCtaCobro " & _
              "FROM RecibodeIngresos WHERE Númdedocidentif= '" & [Forms]![frm_ProveedoresRecibodeingresosconcepto]![Númdedocidentif] & "'")

Pero desafortunadamente el mismo error 3075 persiste
Muchas gracias por la colaboración que me puedan brindar

¿Cuando ejecutas la consulta, que son los valores de "RecibodeIngresos.IdCtaCobro" y "[Forms]![frm_ProveedoresRecibodeingresosconcepto]![Númdedocidentif]"? ¿Puedes imprimirlos?

Hola gracias, entrando en materia los valores de IdCtaCobro es 16 y el de la variable Númdedocidentif es 0402  que lastima que no le pueda enviar captura de pantalla.

Con el valor de RecibodeIngresos.IdCtaCobro como 10, creo que el problema es con el comando "Top".  El formato del comando "Top" es:
Select Top N

Donde "N" es un número único y es el número máximo de resultados a devolver.  Pero con tu consulta tienes:
SELECT TOP 1 RecibodeIngresos.IdCtaCobro FROM RecibodeIngresos ...

Donde RecibodeIngresos.IdCtaCobro el valor de 16.  Entonces, tu consulta se convierte:
SELECT TOP 1 16 FROM RecibodeIngresos ...

Creo que tu consulta debería ser
SELECT TOP RecibodeIngresos.IdCtaCobro FROM RecibodeIngresos ...

El error que recibiste es 3075: "Operador faltante".  Lo recibiste porque Access quería ver un operador entre "1" y "RecibodeIngresos.IdCtaCobro" para sumirlos para formar un solo número.
Finalmente hay otra forma de Top:
Top N PERCENT

Esta forma cambiará "N" del número de resultados al porcentaje de resultados a devolver.
